# Can the probabilities of classification trees be compared with the ones from logistic regression?

Tags: probability, classification, interpretation, conditional-probability, cart

When I use the same data set to estimate a tree and a logistic regression model. Is there a way of comparing the resulting probabilities? In my view, there is not. Because, for logistic regression, I look at the effect a particular feature has on the outcome holding all the features constant (for example). But for classification trees, I only get conditional probabilities dependent on features further up the tree. Is this a correct reasoning?

Comment: There is no reason you cannot compare them, as a way of helping understand the diference between the models.

Comment: The following could be relevant:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164048/can-a-random-forest-be-used-for-feature-selection-in-multiple-linear-regression/164068#164068