# Post-Lasso OLS: What does statistical significance mean?

Tags: statistical-significance, least-squares, lasso

I'm doing Post-Lasso OLS i.e. running a Lasso regression on some data, and then running an OLS regression with only the variables that had non-zero coefficients when doing Lasso.

Should I care about statistical significance in the OLS stage? If so, how? Using the standard threshold of statistical significance feels a bit conservative to me, given that the variable was already shortlisted in the first stage by Lasso. To give a concrete example, I feel uncomfortable saying that there is not enough evidence to conclude there is a correlation simply because a coefficient has a t-statistic of (say) 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

The statistical inference (p-values etc) for OLS post-lasso is going to be invalid.

In general, your standard errors are going to be too small since OLS disregards the uncertainty in the model selection phase. Post-lasso inference is [quite involved](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.6238) and I do not have the confidence to be able to explain all the details.

For applied work, you might want to take a look at the [HDCI package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HDCI/index.html), and its function `?LassoOLS`.

I hope this helps.

PS. Here's a related question [How does it make sense to do OLS after LASSO variable selection?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253641/how-does-it-make-sense-to-do-ols-after-lasso-variable-selection)