# Feature Selection for Neural Networks: Questions on Linearity and application

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, pca, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I am using neural networks for time series prediction and am completely new to the process.  I have 6 covariates in total.  Since I am doing time series prediction, I have decided to use several lags of each variable while also including lags of my dependent variable.  In total, I have a data frame with 49 possible variables to use.

I *literally* do not have the time to go through every combination of possible variables and parameters of the network so I have decided on some feature selection processes.  I have two questions.

First, if I suspect the underlying data generating process of my dependent variable to be non-linear, does using feature selection methods that are linear, like PCA, hinder the ultimate outcome?

Second, is it appropriate to use non-neural network feature selection methods to find features to then use in the final neural network?

Thanks in advance for any advice/answers!

Comment: This is only somewhat related to your second question, but I think it illustrates the kind of thinking that you'll have to do to decide whether feature selection is portable between two different modeling approaches. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164048/can-random-forest-be-used-for-feature-selection-in-multiple-linear-regression/164068#164068